# Select query - how to show results while query is executing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing a SQL Server query that looks like:

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1='12345'
```

Since the database is too big, the query takes more than 1 hour to execute. If I stop the query at let's say 30 minutes, I get 20+ rows appearing as results.

Is there a way to see these rows sequentially as they are fetched without having to wait for the query to finish or without having to stop the query?

Comment: Off-topic compared to your question and I'm sure this is already the case, but have you added an index to `Column1`? This could dramatically improve the performance of the query.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: The answer to your question is no. But just look at whatever tool you are using because you *may* be seeing say 10 minutes of query and 50 minutes of transferring results, depending on network speed etc. But the query shouldn't produce any result till it's done.

Comment: @Martin I only have read rights to the DB. How can I check what are you asking?

Comment: @jarlh varchar(100)

Comment: @adrCoder Execute this: `EXEC sys.sp_helpindex N'Table1'` and you will be shown the indexes that exist on the table

Comment: @Martin I get this result: `index_name index_description index_keys
name1 clustered, columnstore located on PRIMARY NULL`

Comment: @adrCoder You must add an index to `Column1`.  Depending upon the size of your table it may take some time to build, but your query is likely to be significantly faster once this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will help you to see the first 20 rows without required to stop the query.You can use the order by statement before the OPTION hint which like as the below;

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1 = '12345'
OPTION ( FAST 20)

select *
from Table1
where Column1 = '12345'
order by Column1
OPTION ( FAST 20)
```

Also you can see this link for more detail [FAST number_rows hint](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/26/sql-server-challenge-puzzle-usage-of-fast-hint/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because of concurrent transactions, so use `nolock` keyword as below

```
select * from Table1 WITH NOLOCK
where Column1='12345'
```

Comment: This question is trying to see the data *as it is fetched* by the query, not running multiple `select` statements at the same time.  Your answer has completely missed the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query. It will fetch data very fastly. Maybe it will work for you.

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 = '12345' option(maxdop 4)
```

Comment: Why do you think this will help?  What do the additional `option`s add to the query?  Bear in mind this question is about *returning data to the screen* faster and not finishing the query faster.

Comment: @iamdave, Thnaks for your feedback. I'm not sure. I just told suggession. I used this option, Its helped me to fetch data very fastly.